# How can I step through the Prism code?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am writing a WPF application with Prism and I was wondering it is possible to step through the source code?

Comment: It is open source: [link](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong, you can do that with PDB files (put them at same level of your dll in directory structure). Also you can easily get [sources](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) of prism so you can eventually make it a project referenced to yours so you can easily break in source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is referencing Prism DLL:s. Go to folder where DLL:are. Take one of .pdb files and open it with notepad. You will find paths like 'c:\prj\PrismNew\Prism4\WorkingDir\PrismLibraryBuild\PrismLibrary\Desktop\Prism.Interactivity\InteractionRequest\InteractionRequestTrigger.cs'. Download Prism source code, and put it on your computer to folder that matches path found on .pdb. I know this it a hack but it works.